# Linkable Images

Tags: html, css

I know how to make a linkable images. My question is I want to be able to customize it more with having that an image that is linked e.g.  I only want those images to have an opacity added to it so my other images are unaffected. Is there a way to accomplish that?

Comment: Please share some code where you can show us how you linked them. Do you use Javascript or do you wrap the image with an a-tag?

Answer (score 0):

Set the CSS for your standard img first, then set the CSS for an image that is linked:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

  <head>

    <style>

      /* STANDARD IMAGE */
        img {
           opacity: 1;
      }

      /* LINKED IMAGE */
         a img {
            opacity: .5;
         }

      </style>

  </head>

 <body>

   Linked Image:<br><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150"></a>

   <br><br>Standard Image:<br><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">

  </body>

</html>​
```

Comment: he want linked images to have opacity for ex: 0.5 others 1